# Collapse groupings in reports

Tags: reporting, report-chart

Is there a way to collapse a grouping? This seems like a basic feature but I cannot find it.

In this example I don't want to see all the values, I just want to see the grouping name and the percent to the right. The percent is a formula as well using the Total Enrolled column in the formula
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that you can do is to click the button at the top of the report that says 'Hide Details'.

Then they offer the ability to drill down more specifically at the bottom of the report.

Comment: To add, when you define the report in edit mode, there is an option in the middle bottom pane to uncheck show details. Thus the default behavior for that report will be to have them collapsed

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense. Sometimes when I make reports it starts with show details unchecked and in the tabular report style it won't show anything. I didn't even think about clicking that. Thanks!!